# River drainage basin boundary

Tags: data, dem, united-kingdom, hydrography, catchment-area

I'm looking for a set of outlines of the river basins in the UK - I don't need a particularly detailed or highly accurate map - just a map saying point X will drain into the Thames or point Y will just go into the sea!  Just the main river names would be fine.  I have the full Environment Agency rivers set and the OS DTMs if I want... but how do I convert this into a catchment boundary?

Comment: Sorry I should also have specified that I'm looking for a shapefile or similar.

Comment: and a catchment name too please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform a [watershed analysis](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial_62_en/htdocs/esercitazione/dtm/dtm4.html) yourself, but its a time consuming process. One  good source of existing river catchment data is the [HydroSHEDS project](http://hydrosheds.cr.usgs.gov/), which provides high resolution basins for much of the globe, including the UK.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to Google "UK river catchment map".  (Other combinations that include "watershed" don't work.)  You will find

- [River basin management plan](http://www.euwfd.com/html/rbmps_in_england_and_wales.html) documents.
- [River basin district maps](http://www.wfduk.org/implementation/RBDmapfiles/view) (downloadable files).
- An [interactive map](http://maps.ehsni.gov.uk/wmuviewer/).
- Maps by the [UK Environment Agency](http://maps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/wiybyController?x=357683.0&y=355134.0&scale=1&layerGroups=default&ep=map&textonly=off&lang=_e&topic=wfd_rivers).
- [Scottish river basin maps](http://www.sepa.org.uk/water/river_basin_planning.aspx) and data.

A search involving "watershed" did turn up a [historical (1883) map](http://www.davidrumsey.com/maps1150320-31373.html) in the Rumsey Map Collection.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a map, SAGA GIS has a module called watershed basins that uses a dem and the channel network (your rivers). If you use a coarse dem this goes fast.
http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_modules_doc/ta_channels/index.html

Answer (score 1):

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/integrated-hydrological-units-of-the-united-kingdom-catchments has data for catchments in GB, but not Northern Ireland.
Although derived from a lower resolution grid than EA Lidar, these should be sufficient for most purposes