# Splitting polygon by line layer extents using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am using QGIS.

I have a map of UK rivers. I want to make a polygon layer of the UK which is split up into segments of the extents of each river. Similar to a river catchment boundary. Each river is its own line in the attribute table.

I've tried to do this with Voronoi polygons. However, it is taking too long.

I essentially want to take this:

[image]

And make it like this:

[image]

Comment: The [Concave Hull](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/concavehull/) plugin for QGIS may do what you want. You can group the output by the unique identifier for each river. It probably won't be perfect, though.

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/river-drainage-basin-boundary help

Comment: @IanTurton the rivers are not strictly river catchments as some are joined and some are smaller than the data in those datasets. So I'm really looking for a method for this. Thankyou though!

Comment: With voronoi polygons, how long is "too long"? Have you tried for a small subset? Could you simplify/generalise the river network a bit?

Comment: @Spacedman I'd left it running for 2 days and it was still running. I'm trying to simplify the number of points to use now.

Comment: My 2014-era PC took 14 minutes to compute voronoi polygons on 194,000 points in the UK (nodes from a river network). The data didn't have the underlying catchment value to do a dissolve like you need to do. How many points you got?

Comment: @Spacedman I think there is about 300,000. Can I ask did you use the geometry tools voronoi or the Grass one v.voronoi?

Comment: Vector: Geometry Tools: Voronoi Polygons, no buffer extent. Data was in epsg:27700. 194,000 points over Great Britain (England, Wales, Scotland). Its possible there was something pathological in your 300,000 points made it infinite loop...

Comment: Is the river dataset open data? Can you share a link to it? That way the collective swarm intelligence could go at it like beavers at a birch tree (sorry...) and try it out.

Comment: @til_b Yes.. https://beta.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/products/os-open-rivers

Comment: Did you pre-process the data? Because you seem to have river segments joined together (at least you have a common color for one "river system", whereas the ordnance survey data I downloaded does not have a field from which I can determine which segment belongs to which river.

Comment: @til_b Yes i did. I dissolved and then made into multiparts.